# failed to open VSTS 2008 project file

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I have an ASP.Net VSTS 2008 project and the project depends on database (SQL Server 2005), it could be opened by VSTS 2008 fine when the machine installed with SQL Server 2005. But when I copy the project to another computer without SQL Server 2005 installed, there is error message like this, any ideas what is wrong?

Failed to create Microsoft Visual C# 2008 editor, because of failed to open project "FOO", QueryService for {} failed

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, found the solution in a belgian forum post

http://www.computerfaq.be/visual-studio/visual-studio-error-compiler-could-not-be-created/

open a visual studio command promt, and run the following

devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs

Solved the problem for me, next time i opened visual studio the regular way and it was still solved

Comment: This also fixed the problem on my system

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's not lack of sql server that's causing this, it's some other visual studio plugin or package.   In QueryService for {}, is there a guid in between those brackets?

Comment: Yes, there is a GUID, value is 74946829-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF. Any further ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Trying to figure out which package is causing the problem by its guid, but whatever it is, I don't have it. Live and Google don't seem to have an answer either. There are a couple of msdn posts that talk about possible solutions.  One is to reinstall silverlight if you have that installed, the other editing the registry to disable that package.   

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsexpress2008installationandsetup/thread/3985f82d-c340-48ec-bd00-589ce451c7c4/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/04be49aa-de6b-4f45-9a27-86e3f214a0fe/

Comment: Cool, the second solution makes more senses, but I am confused about the 1st solution, why Silverlight may cause this issue? My project is not using Silverlight.

Comment: I find it from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\Services\{74946829-37a0-11d2-a273-00c04f8ef4ff}, looks like it is a part of SQL Server, not a part of VSTS?

Comment: On the problem machine, can you open any project in VS?  If it's just this project causing the problem, and the project doesn't use Silverlight, then you're right it's probably not Silverlight.

Just be careful w/ the registry.  :)

Comment: Ah ok, so it is part of sql server.  How does your project require sql server?  Do you have a reference to the sqlclient?  Does the solution contain a database project?   Are both machines running the same version and edition of Visual Studio?

Comment: I develop ASP.Net and SQL Server on the same development machine. what do you mean a reference to the sqlclient? I just use ADO.Net in ASP.Net project to connect to SQL Server 2005. Any hints or ideas what is wrong?

Comment: BTW: the project which fails to open is .csproj, it should be C# project and not database project, correct?

Comment: Sounds like under the hood you're using sqlclient, but that installs w/ the framework (with visual studio).   I hate to take the easy way out, but have you tried reinstalling visual studio on the problem machine?   

Even if the problem machine didn't have any version of sql server installed, I would think the project would still load in visual studio.

Comment: Tom, 1. I have tried to open the project file on a machine without SQL Server installed, and the project could be opened directly. Seems like the specific machine VSTS intallation issue? Agree? 2. SQLClient you mean ADO.Net? 3. {74946829-37a0-11d2-a273-00c04f8ef4ff} on my machine maps to IVSMDDesignerService in registry, do you know what is it? I can not find much information on MSDN.

Comment: Yes I agree it sounds like it may be machine specific.   Especially considering what you found that guid maps to.   I'd just reinstall, if that's an option.  

Yes by sqlclient, I mean ado.net.  System.Data.SqlClient is where most of the classes you're probably using to communicate w/ Sql Server reside.

Comment: Last question, {74946829-37a0-11d2-a273-00c04f8ef4ff} on my machine maps to IVSMDDesignerService in registry (you can find from the screen snapshot from my original question), do you know what is it? I can not find much information on MSDN